# can I change sitemap name in Google Site submission?

Tags: seo, sitemap

I am using `sitemap.xml` for my sitemap, which is traditional naming system. Can I change this as anyName.xml? to prevent to view by third parties.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you want to make sure a file which lists all your pages is available to a huge search engine so that anyone in the world can find all your pages, but you want to hide it from people who might want to read it to view your pages?  I think you might be chasing a red herring!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name it whatever you want according the [sitemaps website](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html).

Comment: above said link not working :)